# Text field should 't allow to enter any data on to it

Tags: forms

I have created a form with some text fields, and based on some conditions I need to disable a text field, that should 't allow to enter data on it.
   I am able to disable the field, but still it allowing to enter data on it.

I used the following code:

```
var thisItem = document.thisItem;
var state = thisItem.getProperty("state");
if(state=="New") {  
  var correction  = getFieldByName("correction");
        if(correction) {
          var correction_Style = correction.style;
          correction.disabled = true;
          correction_Style.visibility = "visible";
          correction_Style.display = "block";       
          correction_Style.readOnly = true;      
       }
}
```

Please help me to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the readonly attribute to the form element as its rendered?  This should stop anyone entering data into it.

```
<form action="form_action.php">
  Country: <input type="text" name="country" value="uk" readonly="readonly" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```